# Unit testing react actions - browserHistory is undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-router, browser-history, ava

I writing tests for my actions, that using

```
{ browserHistory } from 'react-router';
```

And when i'm running my tests, imported browserHistory is undefined for unknown reasons. Therefore, test throws an error - "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined";
I don't know, why browserHistory is undefined, if it works in my app. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 14):

I will guess you are not using karma or any browser to run your test. The object browserHistory will be undefined if there is not a browser. You may need to use sinon to stub your browserHistory. Something like the following maybe helpful:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';
import componentToTest from './component-to-test'
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as router from 'react-router';

var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('Test A Component', () => {

    it('Should success.', () => {
        router.browserHistory = { push: ()=>{} };
        let browserHistoryPushStub = sinon.stub(router.browserHistory, 'push', () => { });
        //mount your component and do your thing here
        expect(browserHistoryPushStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;

        browserHistoryPushStub.restore();
    });

});
```

Comment: The key for me in this answer was the importing of the entire `router` instead of just `browserHistory` or `hashHistory`, which is how I was trying to mock it.

Answer (score 1):

When using watch (`npm run test -- --watch`), I had to save and restore the original `router.browserHistory` to avoid the `Invariant Violation` (below).

```
import * as router from 'react-router'

describe('some description', () => {
  const oldBrowserHistory = router.browserHistory
  after(() => { router.browserHistory = oldBrowserHistory })

  it('some expectation', () => {
    const spy = sinon.spy()
    router.browserHistory = { push: spy }

    // call your code here

    expect(spy.withArgs(expectedArgs).calledOnce).to.be.true
  })
})
```

*Invariant Violation: You have provided a history object created with history v2.x or earlier. This version of React Router is only compatible with v3 history objects. Please upgrade to history v3.x.*

(credit to user3682091 for getting me started on the correct path)