# How to mock browserHistory in unit test environment?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, react-router

I'm trying to test React component which uses browserHistory of react-router. To ensure access to browserHistory I'm using createMemoryHistory (react-router) module like this:

```
let createMemoryHistory = require('react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory');
```

In test env I'm taking advantage of JSDOM library.

```
global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
```

Then I'm trying to assign created history object to DOM:

```
let history = createMemoryHistory();
global.history = history;
```

While rendering component in test environment, I'm getting following error:

> Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM

Any idea how to overcome it?

Comment: You have to implement a mock history object and use that instead

Comment: Any further instructions or code examples?

Comment: You can use sinon/spies to mock out methods you are using. See http://sinonjs.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing react actions - browserHistory is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831788/unit-testing-react-actions-browserhistory-is-undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mock the browserHistory object. You can use `sinon` to create spies or stubs to help you test this.

For example:

**With `spy`**

```
const { createBrowserHistory } =  require('history');

const history = createBrowserHistory(/* ... */);

sinon.spy(history, "push");

// now you should be able to run assertions on history.push

assert(history.push.calledOnce)
```

More on the `spy` and `stub`

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.6/spies/

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.6/stubs/

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are great, but they didn't work for my use case where I was simulating a button click which called `browserHistory.push('/myroute')`.

In my case it was much easier to mock browserHistory in my test file using jest:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

jest.mock('react-router', () => ({
  browserHistory: {
    push: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

...

it('pushes to browserHistory', () => {

    const renderedComponent = shallow(<Component />);

    <<< insert whatever you need to simulate the event that pushes to browserHistory >>>
    const button = renderedComponent.find('.btn');
    button.simulate('click');

    expect(browserHistory.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `jest` as well:

```
const { createBrowserHistory } =  require('history');
const history = createBrowserHistory(/* ... */);
jest.spyOn(history, "push");

// now you should be able to run assertions on history.push
assert(history.push.calledOnce)
```